# pnpm does not resolve dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pnpm

I have my package.json file and if I'm installing all dependencies with `npm i` - everything is ok, but if I'm using `pnpm i` I have exception
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined.`
I do not use this library, I tried to install it manually but with `pnpm i uid` it does not work, only with `npm i uid`

Comment: adding shamefully-hoist=true to my npmrc fixed it for me

Answer (score 8):

Use the `shamefully-hoist` flag set to `true`.

```bash
pnpm i --shamefully-hoist=true
```

Or simply have this file on the same level as your package.json

*/.npmrc*

```
shamefully-hoist=true
```

[`shamefully-hoist` docs](https://pnpm.io/it/npmrc#shamefully-hoist).